# Find partial match in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|4093F6|FFFFFF
```

I would like to find the `chld=1`.

The `1` could be any number and I need to change it.

How can I find `chld=x` where `x` stands for any number?

Comment: `str.replace(/chld=\d/,'chld=3')`

Comment: Should that `\d` be `\d+` instead if it's any number?

Comment: My god. That was fast. Thank you, regexperts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

```js
var re = /chld=\d+/; 
var str = '"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|4093F6|FFFFFF"';
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = str.replace(re, "chld=100");
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

The regex is `chld=\d+` which is very basic:

- `chld=` - Matches literal `chld=` string
- `\d+` - Matches 1 or more digits.

In case you have multiple `chld`s, and you want to set them with the same value, just add `g` flag to `var re = /chld=\d+/g;`. As an alternative to using `\d` you can achieve the same with `[0-9]` character range: `var re = /chld=[0-9]+/g;`. However, in JavaScript, `\d` and `[0-9]` [are equal](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):

> Since certain character classes are used often, a series of shorthand
>   character classes are available. `\d` is short for `[0-9]`. In most
>   flavors that support Unicode, `\d` includes all digits from all scripts.
>   **Notable exceptions are Java, ***JavaScript***, and PCRE. These Unicode
>   flavors match ***only ASCII digits*** with `\d`.**

Comment: I also added an explanation of `\d` and `[0-9]` usage in JavaScript. Best regards.